# How to run separate process from android native binary?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to start my binary file from another my binary file. I know, that I can use `system()` but, i read that is a bad way. I need to do `chmod +x` and after launch file. But when I try to use `chmod` function I got compilation error `use of undeclared identifier 'chmod'`. Where is my error? And how to create process? I must use spawn functions or some other?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

chmod(filepath, S_IRWXU);
```

Comment: If you wish to try a different approach for changing the file permission - using fopen: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2012/may/ndk-file-permissions-gotcha-and-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chmod function can be included with `#include <sys/stat.h>`. There are two stat.h headers in Android NDK. And need to call execve function to start separate process.